# Fixed areas based on cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a splitted layout with two columns. The columns should be separately scrollable. Because I use a special scroll-to function, I can't use `overflow-y: scroll;` or `overflow: auto;`. So I need another idea.

My Needs:

- If cursor is on the left side, the whole page should be scrollable.
  The right area should be fixed while this.
- If cursor is on the right side, the whole page should be scrollable.
  The left area should be fixed while this.

Is it possible with pure CSS? Or maybe with jQuery?

```css
* {
  font-size: 5vw;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

#left,
#right {
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed; /* always only one side should be fixed, the other side should be scrollable */
}

#left {
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  left: 0;
}

#right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>

<div id="right">Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</div>
```

Would be very thankful for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:hover` to detect if a section is being scrolled, and change it's properties. To keep the layout, add the below code in your CSS :

```css
#left:hover,
#right:hover {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

**NOTE :** There is a commented code in CSS here. That is to hide the scrollbars of `#right` and `#left` while getting scrolled. You can see how scrollbars are looking now by running the snippet. Just uncomment in case you need to hide scrollbars.

```css
* {
  font-size: 5vw;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

#left,
#right {
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed; /* always only one side should be fixed, the other side should be scrollable */
}

#left {
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  left: 0;
}

#right {
  right: 0;
}

#left:hover,
#right:hover {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: scroll;
}

/*
Uncomment this if you don't want individual scrollbars to show while scrolling

#left::-webkit-scrollbar, #right::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display:none;
}
*/
```

```html
<div id="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>

<div id="right">Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</div>
```